# Using columns in window function that are not in Group By, I get : SQL compilation error: [COLUMN_A] is not a valid group by expression

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I've seen a lot of questions about this error, the closest one (as it's using window function) to my issue would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984820/snowflake-sql-compilation-error-is-not-a-valid-group-by-expression)

---

My issue is that I use columns in the windows function that are not grouped by :

```
SELECT
    Col_A,
    Col_B,
    FIRST_VALUE(Col_C) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A, Col_B
                            ORDER BY Col_TimeStamp ASC 
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
    MAX(Col_D) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A, Col_B
                            ORDER BY Col_TimeStamp ASC
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM mytable
    GROUP BY 
        Col_A,
        Col_B
```

With that query, I get the error for `Col_C`, `Col_D`, `Col_TimeStamp`

> SQL compilation error: [eachColumn] is not a valid group by expression

I know I can **"make the query work" by adding everything into the GROUP BY clause, but it seems to defeat the purpose** as I'm using a kind of timestamp to Order By.

I have a huge data set and can't easily check if it really does defeat the purpose.

**Is it just me being paranoid or do I miss something ?**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The `first_value()` makes sense, but the `max()` does not in an aggregated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `first_value()` makes sense because there is only one value per group.  However, the `max()` does not make sense.

I wonder if this does what you really want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col_A, Col_B,
       FIRST_VALUE(Col_C) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A, Col_B
                                ORDER BY Col_TimeStamp ASC 
                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                               ),
       MAX(Col_D) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A, Col_B)
FROM mytable;
```

This returns the overall max of `Col_D` for each group.

Comment: Thx, you're right ! I'm refactoring some PySpark to Snowflake and put the group by to define my window frames, but as I can't use them I deleted them but let the group by... :/