# i've to union two different tables sym33 and sym and then check the difference of max svcdate and min svcdate which should be greater then 90 days

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, union-all, year2038

```
create temporary table sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf as (
  select PATIENTID, max(SVCDATE)-min(SVCDATE) as days from symphony_hvh_db.sym33.dx

  union all
  
  select PATIENTID, max(SVCDATE)-min(SVCDATE) as days from symphony_hvh_db.sym.dx
  group by PATIENTID
  having days>90
  limit 100
);
select * from sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf limit 100
```

**error:**
*SQL compilation error: [DX.PATIENTID] is not a valid group by expression*

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Also: When using `LIMIT`, you should also add an `ORDER BY` to be sure to return the records that you expect.

Comment: I'm using snowflake

Comment: The problem seems to be the same as [Snowflake: "SQL compilation error:... is not a valid group by expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984820/snowflake-sql-compilation-error-is-not-a-valid-group-by-expression), but, sorry, I do not see why you are having "PATIENTID is not a valid group by expression"

Answer (score 1):

You need a group by on both sides of your `UNION ALL` as this is failing because you are using an aggregate function against `sym33.dx` without specifying a group by.  Therefore, PATIENTID is not a valid group by expression in the first select.

```
create temporary table sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf as (
  select PATIENTID, max(SVCDATE)-min(SVCDATE) as days from symphony_hvh_db.sym33.dx
  group by PATIENTID
  having days>90

  union all
  
  select PATIENTID, max(SVCDATE)-min(SVCDATE) as days from symphony_hvh_db.sym.dx
  group by PATIENTID
  having days>90
  limit 100
);
select * from sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf limit 100
```

It's also possible that you wanted to union all and then do the group by.  You'd need to do a sub-select like this:

```
create temporary table sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf as (
  select a.PATIENTID, max(a.SVCDATE)-min(a.SVCDATE) as days from
  ( 
    select PATIENTID, SVCDATE from symphony_hvh_db.sym33.dx
    union all
    select PATIENTID, SVCDATE from symphony_hvh_db.sym.dx
  ) a
  group by PATIENTID
  having days>90
  limit 100
);
select * from sand_scipher_ds_db.public.Rf limit 100
```